# Ubuntu 19.04 Multiple Monitors changes could not be saved - could be hardware limitation

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have a Raedon Tahiti HD 7090 - fully supported hardware.  When I try to set up my displays I cannot apply changes because "Changes Cannot be Applied" "This could be due to hardware limitations".  All thee displays show the background image but only one is active.  I am trying to convert from windows where this was not a problem.